# Full import URL DataImportHanlder

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have configured my solr data import handler, and now want do to full import. On Solr Wiki page I have found that one way to check my config is:

> Hit _http://local_host:8983/solr/db/dataimport with a browser to verify the configuration.

Is this correct and what would parameter "db" be in previous URL? I assume it is one of parameters I entered somewhere earlier, but it is not clear which. It is not written on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Url you are looking for is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/{collection_name}/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Tutorial:

- http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/11/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-1/
- http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/01/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-2/
- http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/22/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-3/

Answer (score 1):

This command is for Full-import via URL.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://local_host:8983/solr/db/dataimport \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8983' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -d 'command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&wt=json&indent=true&verbose=false&optimize=false&debug=false'
```